# Adding another font on another language

Tags: css, html

Hi I want to add another font to english words in my website.
maybe i can do it with javascript code that add span to those words?

thanks for help

```
    window.englishExp = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
    (function (count) {

      'use strict';
      (function wrap(el) {
        $(el).contents().each(function () {
          if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
             if(window.englishExp.test($(this).text().trim().charAt(0)))
                {
                wrap(this);
                }
          } else if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            var val = $.trim(this.nodeValue);
            if (val.length > 0) {
              $(this).replaceWith($.map(val.split(/\s+/), function (w) {
                return $('<span>', {id: count = count + 1, text: w}).get();
              }));
            }
          }
        });
      }('body'));
    }(1));
```

Comment: Do you have a list of this english words or do you need a way to recognize them? And, moreover, why you want to do it in javascript and don't you process it statically?

Comment: i want to do it on all words in document

Answer (score 2):

You could use the CSS `:lang()` selector:

```
span:lang(en) { 
    background: yellow;
}
```

And have `spans` thus:

```
<p>¿Cómo se dice <span lang="en">Hello</span> en español?</p>
```

```css
span:lang(en) {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p>¿Cómo se dice <span lang="en">'hello'</span> en español?</p>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_lang.asp

Comment: but i want to add it by javascript withot need to set the span in my own

Comment: Unless you have a list of the specific foreign words used in your site, this is probably not practical @lirondeveloper